How to remap missing iso-layout key to unused using VIA keyboard software
On ISO keyboard layout there is an extra key between left-shift and qwerty-Z key.
I'm using a azerty-BE keyboard layout on an ANSI keyboard which does not have that key.
In azerty-be layout the extra key is used for < > \.
The key qwerty-| key, between enter and backspace has µ £ on azerty-be, these are not really useful for me.
I'd like to remap qwerty-| to the extra key as shown in the image


I fiddled some more and I have found the answer. I still think this could be useful to other users so I'll post the answer as well.
In the https://usevia.app/ app

Select configure
Select the correct layer, in my case on a keychron keyboard it's layer 2 for Windows
Select the key you want to remap
go to Special
select the any key
enter the keycode for the missing key, the key I'm missing has code 0x66 (source https://forum.tekgear.com/t/the-key-between-left-shift-and-z/154/6)


After saving via show the key as KC_NUBS

I also mapped the layer 3 key to the original so that I can still use it when holding Fn

